# Get the max and min values from each row (unix)

Tags: unix, max, min

I have a dataset tab delimited with multiple columns and rows:

```
ID      v1    v2     v3     v4     v5    v6     v7     v8     
CR_A    2.0657669  1.8515346 2.0644004   0.58573062  2.4229691  1.0294456   1.640186   4.1076807
LR_57   0.83709141 1.097222  1.1135779   0.84598841  1.4768965  0.82643804  1.8255887  2.9050872
CR_t1t  1.3008098  1.0157919 0.76411066 -0.56374447  1.4978799  0.016129955 1.7124357  2.4607684
```

I would like to have the min and max values of each row. For example:

```
CR_A     0.58573062  4.1076807
LR_57    0.84598841  2.9050872
CR_t1t   -0.56374447 2.4607684
```

I was able to calculated just min values:

```
cat file | grep -v ID | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {$1=($i<$1)?$i:$1} print $1}'
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to overwrite exisiting data as you are doing `$1=(...)`.  Why not just use separate variables like `min` and `max` and compare  against them? It's a little tricky on the `max` side of things, but it will be a fun programming problem for you to solve. Also, you can reduce the number of processes used by adopting the form `awk '$0 !~/^ID/{..code}' file`  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put everything into a new file

```
awk  'NR>1{a=0; b=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i < a || i == 1)a = $i; else if($i > b|| i == 1)b = $i; print $1,a, b}' test.txt > new_file2
```

NR>1 skips the first line which are columns name. Go through each row, save max and min and print the name, min, and max. Hope it helps.

My Output. The desired output you have above is wrong because the min of row CR_t1t is not 1.7.1234 like you have written but actually 2.4607684.

```
CR_A 0.58573062 4.1076807
LR_57 0.82643804 2.9050872
CR_t1t -0.56374447 2.4607684
D10 -0.4515 2.2971
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This code gives the correct min values, but the max values are not correct...

Comment: Check the edit, I think the output you wrote has a wrong value for the third row maximum value and should really be 2.4607684

Comment: You are right, I edited the question. I am using your code for another similar dataset that I have, so I am not sure why is not working.

Comment: Can I see the dataset.

Comment: only diference is that I have more columns, for example of 1 row: D10  0.7552  -0.3039  0.2974   2.2971   0.3155  -0.4515  0.0050    1.5315   1.2750   2.4316   1.4391  0.1278